# Create an authentication system with a predefined unique password

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

I will want to set up an input on an html page which will ask for
a predefined password in the program, so that when the predefined password is entered,
access to a third party page is executed.
Ideally, the code would have to be JavaScript to be able to integrate it,
but I don't know much about it. I did an equivalent in python (code at the bottom),
if anyone could translate the code to js and implement it in an html page.

```
   identification = True 
   while identification : 
    user_password = input("Le mdp : ") #Empty input in the middle of the page 
    if user_password == mdp: 
            print("allowed access") #Redirection to the third party page via a button 
        else: print("x") 
            continue          #End of loop, user must enter password again
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This solution prompts the user for a password, checks it against `mdp`, and if so redirects to `http://redirection.page/`. Please note that this isn't secure as anyone can just inspect the page (Ctrl+Shift+I) and see the plain text password.

```html
<script>
var mdp = "PASSWORD"; //Put password here
var identification = true;
while (identification) {
  var user_password = prompt("Le mdp:");
  if (user_password == mdp) {
    alert("Access allowed");
    break;
  } else {
    alert("Access denied");
  }
}
//Your code here
location.href = "http://redirection.page/";
</script>
```